# Overlay two plots on top of each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am working with two plots.

**Plot 1** : Stem and Leafplot

```
data("mtcars")
x <- mtcars$wt
stem(x)


 1 | 5689
 2 | 123
 2 | 56889
 3 | 22224444
 3 | 55667888
 4 | 1
 4 | 
 5 | 334
```

**Plot 2** : The Z values for these data points

```
 mu = mean(x)
 sdev <- sd(x)

 y <- (1/(sdev * sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-((x-mu)^2)/(2*sdev^2))
 plot(x,y, pch = 8)
```

[image]

My goal is to overlay these two plots on top of each other. The expected plot would look something like this. Any suggestions or help is much appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `stem` function doesn't return anything, which makes life difficult. Plus, the code is written in C, which is available [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/src/stem.c). I've tried to replicate the `stem` function using simple R functions and this certainly doesn't match the C code, but it works for this sample dataset. I certainly haven't incorporated any of stem's arguments (scale, width, atom).

```
data(mtcars)

x <- mtcars$wt
stem(x) # you can see the result from the question.

mu = mean(x)
sdev <- sd(x)

y <- (1/(sdev * sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-((x-mu)^2)/(2*sdev^2))
```

This is your density plot:

```
par(mar=c(2,1,1,1))
plot(x, y, pch = 8, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ylab="", col="grey)
```

Now we need to reinvent the `stem` function from scratch. I first use the `hist` function to define to "best" breakpoints, which I'm *guessing* is similar to what `stem` does.

```
h <- hist(round(x,1), right=FALSE, plot=F)
bin <- h$breaks; bin
#[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5
```

Then I use cut to assign the x values into the correct bins.

```
xgr <- sort(cut(round(x,1), breaks = bin, right=FALSE, labels = FALSE, include = TRUE))
```

Then I use the `rowid` function from **data.table** to define the y-axis values, dividing by its length to get the densities so that the two plots are using the same y-axis system.

```
library(data.table)
y <- rowid(xgr)/length(xgr); y
```

The actual characters to plot (`pch`) come from the first digit after the decimal place.

```
pch <- as.character(round(10*(round(sort(x),1) %% 1))); pch
# [1] "5" "6" "8" "9" "1" "2" "3" "5" "6" "8" "8" "9" "1" "2" "2" "2"
#[17] "4" "4" "4" "4" "5" "5" "6" "6" "7" "8" "8" "8" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

And finally the "at" for the x-axis.

```
at <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=length(bin)-1)
x <- rep(at, h$counts)
    
points(x, y, pch = pch, col="red")
axis(side=1, at=at, labels=trunc(bin[-length(bin)]), tck=-0.02, mgp=c(1,0.3,0), col="red", col.axis="red")
```

[image]

A notable difference is that `stem` doesn't use `round` as I've done here. It appears to use `floor(x+0.5)` at lines 96 and 103, which explains the slight differences. Another problem is that it will need tweaking to be more robust.

For example, replacing `x` with `mtcars$drat` would need changing the `scale` argument to 0.5.

```
x <- mtcars$drat
stem(x, scale=0.5)

  The decimal point is at the |

  2 | 889
  3 | 0111112222
  3 | 567778999999
  4 | 111224
  4 | 9
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Edward, this is very interesting and i am studying your example now

Answer (score 0):

`stem()` does not actually produce a typical graphical plot (nor can I save or easily extract information from its structure), so I'm not sure how you can overlay the `stem()` output with a graphical plot, such as those produced by `plot()` or `ggplot()`.

However, one alternative to get the two plot information onto the same plot is to use `ggplot()` with `annotate()` to show the `stem()` information of Plot 1 and `geom_point()` to show the scatter plot of Plot 2.

```
stem(x) # copy and paste this stem-and-leaf plot to a variable
sal <- c("1 | 5689", "2 | 123", "2 | 56889", "3 | 22224444", "3 | 55667888", "4 | 1", "4 | ", "5 | 334")

# make sal into a single string, collapse using new lines ("\n")
sal2 <- paste(sal, collapse="\n\n") # here I am using two new lines to widen the line spacing
sal2 <- gsub("\\|" ," ", sal2) # change the vertical bar ("|") to a space if you want to later replace it with geom_segment() (optional depending on how you like your aesthetics)

sal_x_position <- min(x) + (max(x) - min(x))/2 # the center of x-axis will be the center of the stem-and-leaf
    
df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  # plot Plot 1
  annotate("text", x = sal_x_position, y = 0, label = sal2, angle = 90, hjust = 0, col = "red") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 0.015, xend = 5, yend = 0.015), col = "red") + # add a line between the stems and leaves (caveat: must choose custom coordinates for its location)
  # plot Plot 2
  geom_point(pch = 8) + 
  geom_line() + 
  # customize other plot aesthetics
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image: Overlayed Stem-and-leaf plot with scatter plot]

Note that you can also use `sal` instead of `sal2` if you want more control over where each text is mapped on the plot. You will just have to use multiple layers of `annotate()` and specify each location (*see my original post in edit history for an example*).